# Vue.js + Bootstrap-vue, table data loading from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have been working with Vue.js/Vuex/Bootstrap-vue/Firestore, and have been getting into issues getting data from Firestore to populate the Bootstrap-vue table. Seems like vue needs a refresh, or the firing order isn't the right timing. The reason I say this, if I switch pages, and go back to the "orders page", it will load the data. But not when it comes to browser-refresh.

According to Bootstrap-vue there is something you can run to refresh the data, but for some reason, it's not working for me.

```
this.$emit('refreshed');
```

I also tried using the, **this.isBusy=true|false**, but this too didn't work for me. 
I did also try using **async fetchOrders()** and **await** on the firebase call, and it came back with an empty observer

Here is a rough outline of my code

```
export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
        orders: []
        ,isBusy: false
        }
    }
    ,methods: {
        fetchOrders() {
            let ordersData = []
            let tenant = store.get('user/c7.tenant')

            if (tenant) {
                this.$fb.db.collection('Accounts').doc(tenant).collection('orders').get().then( (snapshot)=> {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        ordersData.push(d.formatOrder(doc))
                    })
                    console.log(ordersData)
                    this.orders = ordersData
                })
            }
        }
    }
    ,beforeMount () {
        this.fetchOrders()
    }
}
```

I hope someone is able to help shed some light on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try this.orders.push(...ordersData) instead? That might fix your issues. Also, just call fetchOrders() in created() rather than beforeMount()

Comment: Hey @Sujil, i just gave that a try, and it was the same result. Any other ideas?